# Is there a way to get earnings from paypal sdk python?

Tags: python-3.x, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

So I have my admin page for my website and I use Paypal to process payments and I was wondering if there is a way to get a report with the total earning. I read the documentation but I only found generating transaction reports.
In case I didn't make my self clear what I mean is I request the API and it returns a float or int with the total earnings so I can display the amount on my admin page.

Comment: How do you define what "earnings" are? You can keep your own running total of all completed transactions and display this value.

Comment: earning would be all the money received from transactions - fees

Comment: and since I'm working with subscription I cant just save the first transaction to the DB and add them up. @PrestonPHX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to calculate a running total minus fees by setting up and [listening for transaction Webhooks](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/webhooks/), specifically `PAYMENT.CAPTURE.COMPLETED`

---

I would just use the Reports features in PayPal.com rather than obsessing about building your own counter.